# Android Kotlin use of Google Cloud

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-storage

Using Android Studio and Kotlin, can one provide the minimal req Gradle.build and Kt code to upload and down load file from my Google drive already existing Project (no SQL required)

Using Google Cloud Free account

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.